# Liferay Web Application Integration (WAI) problem

Tags: web-applications, portlet, liferay

I am trying to get an existing application to show up as a portlet in Liferay.  I have confirmed that the WAR file will deploy in Tomcat/Jetty.  Apparently, I should be able to simply copy the WAR file to Liferay's deploy folder and Liferay will take care of the rest.

The portlet does show up in the 'Add' menu, but I get a 404 error once I have added it.  The path seems to be wrong.

The path Liferay seems to try to go to is: http://localhost:8080/web/guest/home/-/waiapp/jms-gui/

However, the application is running at: http://localhost:8080/jms-gui/secure/jmsPortlet

I'm not sure what to change or how to configure this to get it to work.  Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Michael Kolakowski

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Apparently, I should be able to simply
>   copy the WAR file to Liferay's deploy
>   folder and Liferay will take care of
>   the rest.

No, this isn't true.

Liferay is portlet container.
By "existing application" you probably mean usual java webapp, Servlet API based.
Portlets have their own API, you cannot just take Servlet based webapp and turn it into portlet webapp without changing the code, because Portlets are different from Servlets.

In your case you could probably go for iFrame portlet that would iFrame your webapp, which you can deploy to same Tomcat where Liferay is running, if you wish. 
But you shouldn't deploy it via Liferay deployment procedure, because that's intended for Liferay plugins, not for usual webapps.

Comment: Thanks for the information.  The documentation I read had seemed to imply that Liferay would "generate" a portlet out of a war, which I wouldn't have thought would work, but I'm fairly new to this stuff.  In fact, here is the link:  http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Liferay+Web+Application+Integrator

Comment: You're welcome. 
I haven't been familiar with this WAI thing, so it seems I wasn't quite right actually. 
But, as documentation says, it doesn't really do much more than iFrame, and (as I suspected to be honest) it doesn't seem to work properly.

The path is Liferay Friendly URL path (see http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/FriendlyURLMapper ), but why exactly it doesn't work is hard to say. You may want to check access.log for 404s.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should be able to, though there are some limitations. Here [Liferay Wiki](http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Liferay+Web+Application+Integrator) is the relevant documentation, such as it is. I only discovered this recently by dropping a grails app into my liferay server's hot deploy directory to see what would happen. Once it was deployed I started looking around in the webapps folder and was surprised to see  portlet.xml and liferay-portlet.xml files. Sure enough once I logged in and looked at the Add Portlet menu there was an 'undefined' category and my grails app as a portlet. Authentication isn't shared, and I believe you can break it if your webapp has an outward link off site. Still, pretty fun hack!